# How can you modify the MS Dynamics AX Business Data Lookup Snap-in to select the company to logon to?

Tags: c#, dynamics-ax-2009

Can anyone provide some coding (C#) modification that can be done or any other practical way? or of course point me somewhere that has done it already.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the Snap-In is using the settings from the Business Connector. Find Dynamics AX Configuration utility in the Administators Controlpanel, and point the Business Connector to whatever AOS you want it to connect, and try fill inn chosen company there.